# How do I address fatal error running Composer?

Tags: php, drupal, centos, composer-php

Newbie question: When attempting to run Composer (any command involving Composer like `composer --version`), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'phar://composer.phar/bin/composer' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer on line 24

Composer is in the `$PATH`:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin\
:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin\
:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin\
:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin\
:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin\
:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin\
:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/easy/bin:/usr/local/bin\
:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin\
:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin ## <<< !! SEE HERE !! <<<
```

What is missing in the install of Composer?

System is running CentOS v86.0.40 and PHP 5.5, which I cannot update due to legacy PHP code.

The goal is to update a [Drupal 8 site instance](https://www.energyjustice.net/) (blech) via Composer.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have not outlined in your question which command and how you entered that command to summon this error message. Please add all clarifications to your question by editing it.

Comment: Any command (as now noted).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which version of Composer do you try to run? Maybe you are using v2.5 which is no longer compatible with PHP 5?

Answer (score 0):

How to install composer?

> `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Now, you need to do `chmod +x composer` inside the directory, where it is placed. All as root user.

or you can move to `usr/bin/composer`, notice the extension, first it was `phar` or `php archive` now, the current file has no extension.

Check if you can have `composer --version` and have proper permissions for executing file or data operations.

It is Linux user permissions issues.

Comment: Yes, it can be that straight forward, but then I'd guess the user would not have asked as `composer` is already installed on that system at `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer` and executable. From the error message it looks like that the phar aliasing does not work. This is a pretty technical thing and to be honest, I think the user has more a support request with their software vendor that provides composer to them then a programming for shell programming with composer specifically. But perhaps your answer helps the user to some degree, would be great!

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This is quite helpful, and if installing the correct version or the above does not work, I will report back.  Deeply grateful for the assistance.

Comment: I installed the proper version of composer, set access controls as noted, but still get the same error.  Seems I need to get the server host to fix this.  Will update if that fixes things.